# have an unwanted radio tower

Tags: antenna-construction

I have a 190 foot tall am/fm radio tower I need to take down.  Taking it down with big enough crane and manlifts and a torque crew will be quite expensive.  It is a guyed lattice tower that if necessary I will let fall over by disconnecting one of the guys.  Then of course the tower will be scrap.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You need construction and safety advice, not radio or radio technology advice.

Comment: Can't agrue with that.  Thought perhaps someone here may have had a experience with this type of situation.  Also thought the tower may be of interest to someone before I let it fall and scrap it.  Maybe this isn't the right forum.

Comment: I also have the transmitter and translater and will scrap them I guess.

Comment: Seeing as, in the US, the license exams have several Qs relating to tower safety, I think this is an appropriate question.

Comment: Moving a 190 foot tower pretty much implies bringing it down in sections, the way it was put up originally.  Seems like quite a job.

Comment: I once had a system on a commercial guyed 180 foot tower. A storm blew the sheet metal roof of a building into the tower, buckling it about halfway up. The safest thing was to cut the guys and let it fall, no-one was going to go near it to recover any equipment.

Comment: If I end up falling this tower I thought I'd make it an event.  Not everyday a struture that big comes crashing down :)  I have thought about adding a guyline at the 100 foot connection and removing everything above 125 foot fifth section and then mounting a Bergey wind turbine.  The three legs of the tower are 2 3/8" OD so it is pretty stout.  Heavier than the towers sold with the turbine.

Comment: And then you (or someone) is up a tower that's got 90 feet unsupported, trying to take off sections.  Not me, thanks.

Comment: There is an existing lower guy at 75 feet.  Should have included that info.  The upper guy is at the 150 foot mark.  Would have to manlift a welder to the 100 connection to add eyelets for the guys.  Connect the new guys.  Get a crane to latch onto the tower at 190.  Disconnect the upper guys.  Then have a guy with hydralic torque wrenchs unbolt the connection at 125 foot.   Great caution and attention to detail would be needed.

Comment: There are companies and individuals that specialize in tower work; you should contact one.  BTW cranes and helicopters are used to erect such towers, but there is also a fixture known as a gin pole.  It gets bolted onto a tower section, and it has a vertical pole with a pulley on top.  To take down a tower one could be bolted to the second-highest section, and then a cable goes over the pulley and gets attached to the top section.  The other end of the cable is attached to a winch on the ground.  The bolts attaching the top section are loosened, and the section is winched to the ground.

Comment: Thank you rclocher3.

Comment: Have you considered becoming a ham operator and repurposing the tower for your antenna(s)? (Would also work for Short Wave Listening hobby).

Comment: I have not.  It sounds interesting.  Right now all my attention is cleaning up the doublewide the radio station was housed in and refurbishing it into a dwelling.  They walked out of there and left everything.  Ten office desks, Nineteen computers, a wall of reel to reel and recievers, amps....Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: OMG, you have all that equipment that they left? A dream. Can I have it? And I agree you might want to keep the tower. Or did some insurance company tell you to take it down?

Comment: +1 for not scrapping things that don't need to be scrapped - if you can't find anyone who wants it then it's excusable - but if someone does want it, why scrap it?

Comment: Gunther and 253751,  I ;have been busy cleaning out the station.  Unfortunately all is gone now except the tower and the transmitter.  The transmitter is encased in a 42" x 42" (approx)  5 foot tall metal housing.  There looks to batteries and I don't know what else in there.  It probably wieghs around 500 lbs.  Why its the last.  I can send pictures if you'd like.  Via e'